# Differentiable structure and smoothness of a manifold

Tags: manifolds, smooth-manifolds

I am really confused with graph of $|x|$ has a differentiable structure.

I know that if $X$ is a differentiable manifold homeomorphic to  $Y$ then $Y$ gains differential structre from $X$. But I dont understand why at the singular point these differential structre doesnot fail?

Comment: Because with the new glasses on, you don’t see a singular point!

Comment: so it is like, being a differentiable manifold is not same as having a differentiable structre?

Comment: Sure it is. The question is whether your “subset of usual $\Bbb R^2$” glasses are the right ones.

Comment: so you are referring whether it is submanifold in $R^2$ or as a manifold itself, in that case if we are looking it is just a manifold itself, there is only 1 direction and tangents wont fail? is my loose assessment in the right direction?

Comment: Yes, absolutely.

Answer (score 0):

As you say, if you have a differentiable manifold $X$ with differentiable structure $\mathcal D_X$ and a homeomorphism $h :  X \to Y$ to a topological space $Y$, then $Y$ is a topological manifold which can be given a unique  differentiable $h_*(\mathcal D_X)$  structure such that $h$ becomes a diffeomorphism. Note if $Y$ already has a natural differentiable structure  $\mathcal D_Y$,then in general $h_*(\mathcal D_X) \ne \mathcal D_Y$. In fact $h_*(\mathcal D_X) \ne \mathcal D_Y$ iff $h : (X,\mathcal D_X) \to (Y,\mathcal  D_Y)$ is a diffeomorphism. As an example consider $X = Y = \mathbb R$ with the standard differentiable structure $\mathcal D_\mathbb R$ and $h(x) = x^3$. This is a smooth map, but $h^{-1}$ is not. Thus $h$ is no diffeomorphism and $h_*(\mathcal D_\mathbb R) \ne \mathcal D_\mathbb R$.

I think what may be confusing in your example of the graph $G$  of $\lvert x \rvert$ is that $G$ is not a submanifold of $\mathbb R^2$ (the corner at $x = 0$ prevents this). But this does not prevent us from giving $G$ a differentiable structure. With such a differentiable structure the inclusion $i : G \to \mathbb R^2$ is not smooth.